# Java kinit determining lower case realm from AD domain

Tags: java, windows, active-directory, kerberos

We have an enterprise grade, Java based application on Windows which we want to use Kerberos for Single Sign On with.

We are *not* using any Kerberos config files, like `krb5.conf` or `login.conf`, because we want to keep our clients as simple and change resilient as possible.

It used to work well for some weeks now, only that most people had to re-enter their Windows password for authentication. I will probably post another question about this later.

Now, for some reason the application determines the Kerberos prinicpal to be `username@corp.example.com` instead of `username@CORP.EXAMPLE.COM`. Authentication then fails, naturally, with `krb_error 41 Message stream modified`. Logging off and on again eventually fixes that problem temporarily.

This can be reproduced by using the stock kinit.exe (or calling its class `sun.security.krb5.internal.tools.Kinit`) from the Java JDK. As I didn't find any information about how kinit really behaves when not provided with a principal name, I don't know where to look for any causes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause turns out to be that for some reason windows decides to set the `USERDNSDOMAIN` environment variable to lower case in some cases.

Kinit gets its default realm from there, see link for reference: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/security/krb5/Config.java.html#1071

Now, on to the root cause...